# Memory/Threads leaks, developing simple HTTP-server with WinSock2

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, memory-leaks, winsock

I begin to develop my tool, which works with net at the TCP level, which will present simple functions of web-server.

In testing my program I have got very bad mistakes:

- Memory leaks
- Creating thousands of threads immediately

In taskmgr.exe you may see about ~1,5 of threads and about ~50kb of allocated memory.
Also, I compiled program as 32 bit, but in vmmap utility you may see a lot of 64 bit stacks. My OS is 64 bit, but in taskmgr.exe you may see *32 , I don’t know how 32 bit program uses 64 bit stack, maybe it’s normal for launching 32 bit program in 64 bit OS, but I have no knowledge about this design of OS, so I shall be very pleased , if you give me a piece of advice on this question.

So, why did my program creates immediately a lot of threads? *( I guess , cause of while(true) block )*.

But , I want the next:

- Create each thread for each new request
- When request has been handled, then terminate the thread and free the memory

**How should I remake my code?**

Thanks!

Here is my code ( MS VC ++ 9 ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

typedef struct Header
{
friend struct Net;

private:
    WORD wsa_version;
    WSAData wsa_data;

    SOCKET sock;
    SOCKADDR_IN service;

    char *ip;
    unsigned short port;

public:
    Header(void)
    {
        wsa_version = 0x202;

        ip = "0x7f.0.0.1";
        port = 0x51;

        service.sin_family = AF_INET;
        service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
        service.sin_port = htons(port);
    }

} Header;

typedef struct Net
{
private:
    int result;

    HANDLE thrd;
    DWORD exit_code;

    void WSAInit(WSAData *data, WORD *wsa_version)
    {
        result = WSAStartup(*wsa_version, &(*data));

        if(result != NO_ERROR)
        {
            std::cout << "WSAStartup() failed with the error: " << result << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << (*data).szDescription << " " << (*data).szSystemStatus << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void SocketInit(SOCKET *my_socket)
    {
        (*my_socket) = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

        if((*my_socket) == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            std::cout << "Socket initialization failed with the error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            WSACleanup();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Socket initialization successful!" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void SocketBind(SOCKET *my_socket, SOCKADDR_IN *service)
    {
        result = bind((*my_socket), (SOCKADDR*)&(*service), sizeof(*service));

        if(result == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            std::cout << "Socket binding failed with the error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            closesocket((*my_socket));
            WSACleanup();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Socket binding successful!" << std::endl;
        }

        result = listen(*my_socket, SOMAXCONN);

        if(result == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            std::cout << "Socket listening failed with the error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Listening to the socket..." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    static void SocketAccept(SOCKET *my_socket)
    {
        SOCKET sock_accept = accept((*my_socket), 0, 0);

        if(sock_accept == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            std::cout << "Accept failed with the error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            closesocket(*my_socket);
            WSACleanup();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Client socket connected!" << std::endl;
        }

        char data[0x400];
        int result = recv(sock_accept, data, sizeof(data), 0);
        HandleRequest(data, result);
        char *response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: Amegas.sys-IS/1.0\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\nSet-Cookie: ASD643DUQE7423HFDG; path=/\r\nCache-control: private\r\n\r\n<h1>Hello World!</h1>\r\n\r\n";
        result = send(sock_accept, response, (int)strlen(response), 0);

        if(result == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            std::cout << "Sending data via socket failed with the error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            closesocket(sock_accept);
            WSACleanup();
        }
        else
        {
            result = shutdown(sock_accept, 2);
        }
    }

    static void HandleRequest(char response[], int length)
    {
        std::cout << std::endl;

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            std::cout << response[i];
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    static DWORD WINAPI Threading(LPVOID lpParam)
    {
        SOCKET *my_socket = (SOCKET*)lpParam;
        SocketAccept(my_socket);

        return 0;
    }

public:
    Net(void)
    {
        Header *obj_h = new Header();

        WSAInit(&obj_h->wsa_data, &obj_h->wsa_version);

        SocketInit(&obj_h->sock);
        SocketBind(&obj_h->sock, &obj_h->service);

        while(true)
        {
            thrd = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &Net::Threading, &obj_h->sock, 0, NULL);

            //if(GetExitCodeThread(thrd, &exit_code) != 0)
            //{
            //  ExitThread(exit_code);
            //}
        }

        delete &obj_h;
    }
} Net;

int main(void)
{
    Net *obj_net = new Net();

    delete &obj_net;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't `delete` *pointer-to-pointer*, so use `delete obj_net`, not `delete &obj_net`. (or, better use a smart pointer, like boost::scoped_ptr)

Comment: @Abyx : Or, better use a standard smart pointer, like std::unique_ptr

Comment: @RobertMason, there is no `unique_ptr` in VC++9.

Comment: My bad.  Just trying to get everyone to convert over to C++11.

Comment: If you are going to learn C++, I suggest starting at http://www.learncpp.com/ - this will learn you how to all the BASIC things you NEED to know. From what I've read on that site, it's not difficult English which is important for people who do not speak english natively.

Answer (score 3):

You should create the thread *AFTER* you accept a connection, not before.

What you are doing is creating a ton of threads, and then having each of them wait for a connection.  Many of them have nothing to do.  I don't even know if Windows' accept call is thread-safe - you might end up with multiple threads handling the same connection.

What you need to do instead is, in your main loop (Net's constructor while(true)), you need to call accept().  Since accept() *blocks* until it has a connection, this will cause the main thread to wait until somebody tries to connect.  Then, when they do, you create another thread (or process - more likely on UNIX) to handle that connection.  So, your loop now looks like this:

```
SOCKET sock_accept = accept((*my_socket), 0, 0);

if(sock_accept == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    std::cout << "Accept failed with the error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    closesocket(*my_socket);
    WSACleanup();
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Client socket connected!" << std::endl;
}
thrd = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &Net::Threading, &obj_h->sock, 0, NULL);
//push back thrd into a std::vector<HANDLE> or something like that
//if you want to keep track of it for later: there's more than one thread
```

Then, delete that code you moved from SocketAccept into this loop.  And then, for cosmetic purposes, I would change the name of SocketAccept to SocketHandleConnection.

Now, when your thread starts, it already has a connection, and all you need to do is handle the data (e.g. what you do starting at char data[0x400]).

If you want to handle cleanup for connections, there are a few ways to do this.  One, since you are threaded, you can have the thread do its own cleanup.  It shares memory with the main process, so you can do this.  But in this example, I don't see anything you need to clean up.

Lastly, I think you don't understand what ExitThread does.  According to MSDN:

> ExitThread is the preferred method of exiting a thread in C code. However, in C++ code,
>   the thread is exited before any destructors can be called or any other automatic cleanup
>   can be performed. Therefore, in C++ code, you should return from your thread function.

So it appears that you don't need to call ExitThread- you just return from your function and the thread exits automatically.  You don't need to call it from the main thread.

Finally, you should really (if you can) use the new standard C++ threads in c++11, and then if you put in a little bit of effort to port your code over to boost::asio, you'll have a completely cross platform application, with no need for windows API C ugliness :D

DISCLAIMER:  I only have a passing understanding of Windows as most of my experience is related to UNIX.  I have attempted to be as accurate as I can but if I have any misconceptions about how this knowledge converts over to Windows, well, I warned you.

Comment: could you help me to highlight the code ( the right place ) , how should I change? Thank you very much!

Comment: Stop! What's the difference after or before? Creating/Terminating threads is independent from handling connections in WinSock, cause it's memeory/process management. Thread-leaks are caused not because of handling connections, aren't they?

Comment: See my edited answer.  The thread leaks is by creating huge numbers of threads that don't have anything to do and just sit and wait for a connection forever.  I'm surprised your code hasn't crashed by creating so many threads.  Maybe CreateThread can fail and you're not checking for failure?

Comment: It does work! Funny or not, but does and pretty well handling a lot of requests even in such worst code :)

Comment: Well, I'm surprised.  But that's interesting...  Does this solve your thread issues?

Comment: No! It doesn't help! Because Creating threads in Windows is strongly exist on using cb-function DWORD(WINAPI)(LPVOID), where you pass the arguments for handling through LPVOID argument and casting your object to exact data type in cb-function body (SOCKET *sock = (SOCKET*)lpvoid_arg) etc... When such function was executed, then thread was created, so even Boost or C++ 11 fetures use it. How? It's another question, btw I can't use C++ 11, cause using MSC++, which doesn't support it.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.  MSVC++ 11 beta supports it, and this is supported for production code.  That aside, what I mean is changing the location of your accept() call.

Comment: in the beginning of the topic , I have posted "Here is my code ( MS VC ++ 9 ):", so I'm not using MSC++ 11. Then MSC++ 11 doesn't support fully C++ 11 as I know.

Comment: Yes, but it does support the subset that you would need (it supports the critical 80%, leaving the other 20% for a future release, much like GCC 4.6 released about the same time)

Answer (score 2):

Why are you creating threads in an infinite loop? This will, of course, create tons of threads. I am referring to this piece of code:

```
while(true)
    {
        thrd = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &Net::Threading, &obj_h->sock, 0, NULL);
}
```

Comment: becuase there may coming new connections and how should I handle them? As I understood, for each new connection I must create new thread , then handle it, so how could I develop it? Thank you!

Comment: Create the thread after you have Accept'ed a new socket. But call Accept only on one special thread.

Comment: One special thread? What does it mean "one special"? Sorry for silly questions.

Comment: Just use one thread only for accepting. And start one new thread for each accepted socket.

Comment: It's the main thread.  You have to look at *why* you are creating threads.  You have one thread that manages all the others.  Call this your main thread.  It then spawns threads as needed to handle connection requests from clients.  After you call accept(), you get a socket.  You then give this socket to the thread and tell it to handle the connection on that socket.